# Why additive noise needs to be calibrated with sensitivity in differential privacy?

Tags: security, cryptography, privacy, tensorflow-federated

As a beginner to differential privacy, I would like to why the variance for noise mechanisms needs to be calibrated with sensitivity? What is the purpose of that? What happens if we don't calibrate it and add a random variance?

Example scenario [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_noise_mechanisms) In Laplacian noise, why scale parameter is calibrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can understand this intuitively is by imagining a function that returns either of two values, say 0 and a for some real a.

Suppose further that we have an additive noise mechanism, so that we end up with two probability distributions on the real line, as in the image from your attached link (this is an example of the setup above, with a=1):

[image: LaplacianDistributions]

In pure DP, we are interested in computing the maximum of the ratio of these distributions over the *entire* real line. As the calculation in your link shows, this ratio is bounded everywhere by e to the power of epsilon.

Now, imagine moving the centers of these distributions further apart, say by shifting the red distribution further to the right (IE, increasing a). Clearly this will place less probability mass from the red distribution on the value 0, which is where the maximum of this ratio will be achieved. Therefore the ratio between these distributions at 0 will be increased--a constant (the mass the blue distribution places on 0) is divided by a smaller number.

One way we could move the ratio *back down* would be to "fatten" the distributions out. This would correspond pictorally to moving the peaks of the distributions lower, and spreading the mass out over a wider area (since they have to integrate to 1, these two things are necessarily coupled for a distribution like the Laplace). Mathematically we would accomplish this by increasing the variance in the Laplace distribution (increasing b in the parameterization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_distribution)), which has the effect of *lowering* the peak of the blue distribution at 0 and *raising* the mass the red distribution places at 0, thereby reducing the ratio between them back down (a smaller numerator and a larger denominator).

If you perform the calculations, you will find that the relationship between the variance parameter b and the sensitivity of the function f is in fact linear; that is, setting b to be

[image: b_linear_in_sensitivity]

fixes the maximum of this ratio, to

[image: e_to_epsilon]

which is precisely the definition of pure differential privacy.

Answer (score 1):

If you add arbitrary amounts of random noise, you simply end up with random data. Sure, it preserves privacy, but at the same time as destroying any real value in the data. The noise you add needs to match your existing distribution so that it preserves privacy *without* destroying the value of the data. That’s what the calibration step does.

Comment: Your explanation is intuitive and I understand that. Thank you. Is there a way to simply replicate this and visualize? I am finding it hard to visualize it.